# Debian headless server connected to Ethernet interface ~50% packet loss accessing the Internet

Tags: debian, networking, ethernet, ping, internet

I already did a bunch of troubleshooting in the last three days regarding this issue. Here are the tests and the observations I made so far:

- Internet connection to my server is dropping constantly (see ping below)
- Server has static address and the address is out of the DCHP Range of the router
- Modem is a Modem/Router used in Bridged mode. (Reset to factory settings 3 times now)
- I tried 3 different routers = same results 50% packet loss
- I tried two different physical interfaces = same 50% packet loss
- I tried 3 different Ethernet cables = same 50% packet loss
- I stopped many of my processes on my server simultaneously (see the list below)
- I disabled my firewall
- My connections from the clients to the server on my LAN is always 100% packet received
- **Connecting the server directly to the modem showed no packet loss while pinging 8.8.8.8**
- Got nothing unusual in dmesg or journalctl when the Internet connection failures happen
- Connecting the Ethernet cable in my laptop instead of the server results in no packet loss from the laptop while pinging 8.8.8.8
- **Booting a Arch Linux from a USB drive gives me no problem with the Internet whatsoever.**

I figured at that point that this must be a software related issue. But now I'm stuck.
Here's my **ping results**. It's basically the same every time I run it under the different environments I tried listed below.

```
 ➜  ~ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=14.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=14.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=119 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=119 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=119 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=119 time=2052 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=119 time=1024 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=119 time=16.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=119 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=119 time=19.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=119 time=23.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=119 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=16 ttl=119 time=18.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=17 ttl=119 time=26.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=18 ttl=119 time=18.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=31 ttl=119 time=24.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=32 ttl=119 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=33 ttl=119 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=34 ttl=119 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=35 ttl=119 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=36 ttl=119 time=14.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=37 ttl=119 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=38 ttl=119 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=39 ttl=119 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=40 ttl=119 time=16.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=41 ttl=119 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=42 ttl=119 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=43 ttl=119 time=33.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=44 ttl=119 time=21.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=45 ttl=119 time=19.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=46 ttl=119 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=47 ttl=119 time=30.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=48 ttl=119 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=49 ttl=119 time=14.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=50 ttl=119 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=52 ttl=119 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=53 ttl=119 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=54 ttl=119 time=14.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=55 ttl=119 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=56 ttl=119 time=20.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=57 ttl=119 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=58 ttl=119 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=59 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=60 ttl=119 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=61 ttl=119 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=62 ttl=119 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=63 ttl=119 time=14.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=64 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=65 ttl=119 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=66 ttl=119 time=14.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=85 ttl=119 time=2080 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=86 ttl=119 time=1056 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=87 ttl=119 time=32.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=88 ttl=119 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=89 ttl=119 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=90 ttl=119 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=91 ttl=119 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=92 ttl=119 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=93 ttl=119 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=94 ttl=119 time=17.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=95 ttl=119 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=117 ttl=119 time=16.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=118 ttl=119 time=13.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=119 ttl=119 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=120 ttl=119 time=11.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=121 ttl=119 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=122 ttl=119 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=123 ttl=119 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=124 ttl=119 time=27.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=149 ttl=119 time=960 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=150 ttl=119 time=14.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=151 ttl=119 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=152 ttl=119 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=153 ttl=119 time=26.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=154 ttl=119 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=155 ttl=119 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=156 ttl=119 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=157 ttl=119 time=16.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=164 ttl=119 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=165 ttl=119 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=166 ttl=119 time=21.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=167 ttl=119 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=168 ttl=119 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=169 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=170 ttl=119 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=171 ttl=119 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=172 ttl=119 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=173 ttl=119 time=16.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=174 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=175 ttl=119 time=14.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=176 ttl=119 time=17.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=177 ttl=119 time=16.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=178 ttl=119 time=21.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=179 ttl=119 time=14.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=180 ttl=119 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=181 ttl=119 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=182 ttl=119 time=23.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=183 ttl=119 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=184 ttl=119 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=185 ttl=119 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=186 ttl=119 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=187 ttl=119 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=188 ttl=119 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=189 ttl=119 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=190 ttl=119 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=191 ttl=119 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=195 ttl=119 time=320 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=196 ttl=119 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=197 ttl=119 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=198 ttl=119 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=199 ttl=119 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=200 ttl=119 time=13.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=201 ttl=119 time=17.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=202 ttl=119 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=203 ttl=119 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=225 ttl=119 time=1056 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=226 ttl=119 time=32.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=227 ttl=119 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=228 ttl=119 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=229 ttl=119 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=230 ttl=119 time=21.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=231 ttl=119 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=232 ttl=119 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=233 ttl=119 time=14.5 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
248 packets transmitted, 128 received, 48.3871% packet loss, time 1216ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.806/82.526/2080.231/306.259 ms, pipe 3
```

**Two traceroute executed back to back**

```
➜  ~ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  My WAN IP.mc.videotron.ca (My WAN IP)  19.047 ms  10.699 ms  19.035 ms
 3  10.170.183.146 (10.170.183.146)  20.538 ms  21.036 ms  21.203 ms
 4  72.14.205.46 (72.14.205.46)  20.269 ms  20.188 ms  20.189 ms
 5  108.170.251.17 (108.170.251.17)  20.355 ms 108.170.251.33 (108.170.251.33)  20.149 ms 108.170.251.17 (108.170.251.17)  20.134 ms
 6  108.170.231.63 (108.170.231.63)  21.359 ms 108.170.231.61 (108.170.231.61)  16.538 ms 108.170.231.63 (108.170.231.63)  16.186 ms
 7  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  16.761 ms  15.483 ms  15.866 ms
➜  ~ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * dns.google (8.8.8.8)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
    ➜  ~ cat /etc/network/interfaces                                            
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

#source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug enx00e04c6802a2
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet manual

iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.104
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1
    bridge_ports enp5s0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT 1**

```
➜  ~ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:da:2a:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:da:2a:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
➜  ~ ip -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp5s0           UP             
br0              UP             192.168.3.104/24 fe80::7285:c2ff:feda:2a87/64 
wg0              UNKNOWN        192.168.3.1/24 
➜  ~ ip route;
default via 192.168.3.1 dev br0 onlink 
103.83.20.3 dev wg0 scope link 
103.83.20.4 dev wg0 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.3.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.104 
192.168.3.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.1 
➜  ~ ip neigh
192.168.3.126 dev br0 lladdr 04:6c:59:f6:a0:3b REACHABLE
192.168.3.164 dev br0 lladdr be:95:3a:fc:bf:03 STALE
[PUBLIC IP] dev br0 lladdr c4:04:15:10:b1:bd STALE
192.168.3.127 dev br0 lladdr 4c:3b:df:7f:c6:03 STALE
192.168.3.1 dev br0 lladdr c4:04:15:10:b1:bd REACHABLE
192.168.3.125 dev br0 lladdr 0c:c4:13:18:a4:c5 STALE
192.168.3.144 dev br0 lladdr b8:27:eb:28:4a:98 REACHABLE
➜  ~ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**EDIT 2**
@A.B is right. I forgot to mention I have been running a VPN Server (Wireguard) and it was indeed the problem.

Comment: Your bridge currently only has one slave (enp5s0) and probably isn't necessary at this time. Have you tried setting up enp5s0 as a standalone connection with a static IP address, and disabling the bridge? I don't see anything wrong with your bridge config but this could help isolate the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the actual result of this configuration? With these commands (and a few extra for test): `ip link; ip -br address; ip route; ip neigh; ip rule` + `iptables-save -c` . Don't omit parts you'd think aren't needed, or explain why and what you omitted.

Comment: @Kate I forgot to mention that this config has been this way for a really long time. I didn't touch it since my Internet access stopped working properly. I sure can test it out though just to rule out that possibility.

Comment: @A.B I edited my question to add these outputs. Thanks

Comment: I was thinking about something like "arp flux" considering the 15s works / 15s doesn't work. Doesn't seem like this but for sure something is wrong with "default via 192.168.3.1 dev br0" and at the same time having 192.168.3.1 on dev wg0. So it has to be related to your strange configuration with WireGuard. Disable it and check if it improves the situation. It's also suspicious that you get a public IP in ARP table since it's supposed to be in a separate network (the router's other side). Also you didn't post your iptables rules. More problems could lurk there too.

Comment: Btw, your question initially never hinted you were using a VPN. Don't you think that's something important to tell when it doesn't work, and it's likely the cause of the problems?

Comment: @A.B You got it. I never suspected my VPN Server was the problem so I totally forgot to mention it. It has always worked fine in the past so I never assumed it was the culprit (I have not changed the config in over a year. I did not post my iptables rules since I disabled it for troubleshooting purposes and the issue still occured. I now have to figure out what changed in my network config. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Time to answer your own question and write what you did to solve it even if it's "remove the VPN". As it's an abnormal VPN configuration (reusing the router's IP address as a local IP address for the VPN) I can't tell why it ever worked before except "something changed". Or else delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally disabled my Wireguard server `systemctl disable wg-quick@wg0 && systemctl stop wg-quick@wg0` until I take the time to investigate what was wrong with it and it did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).